# Postgres SQL Join Query

Tags: postgresql

We have one table where there is a column player_id and another transaction_type (deposit || withdrawal)

how to make a request to take the amount of the amount_local column and group it so that it is clear how many deposits there were and how many were withdrawn from one person and group it by player_id

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues. Your current description is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple. You can use SQL's SUM() function together with a CASE statement to discriminate between deposit and withdrawal transactions in order to retrieve the total deposit and withdrawal amounts aggregated by player_id. Here is a sample inquiry:

```
SELECT
    player_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'deposit' THEN amount_local ELSE 0 END) AS total_deposits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'withdrawal' THEN amount_local ELSE 0 END) AS total_withdrawals
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY player_id;
```

`Your_table_name` should be **changed** to the name of your table. The total deposit and withdrawal amounts for each player are determined by adding the values in the `amount_local` column for each `player_id` separately.

Hope this helps, do let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction_type column can be used to distinguish between deposits and withdrawals, and the GROUP BY clause can be used to group the results by player_id. Here is an illustration SQL command for both tables:

```
-- For the first table
SELECT
    player_id,
    transaction_type,
    SUM(amount_local) AS total_amount
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    player_id,
    transaction_type;

-- For the second table
SELECT
    player_id,
    transaction_type,
    SUM(amount_local) AS total_amount
FROM
    table2
GROUP BY
    player_id,
    transaction_type;
```

You will receive a return set from the above query that includes the columns player_id, transaction_type, and total_amount. Transaction_type will either be "deposit" or "withdrawal," and total_amount will be the total of the amounts for each player_id and transaction_type combination.

Hope it works :)